# Aapp working on app engine local browser, but not after deployment

Tags: python, google-app-engine

This is the error. I found this in application' log. It probably has to do something with my applications runtime.

```
2012-12-03 04:06:01.803 /favicon.ico 200 22ms 1kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.14 Safari/537.17
    117.220.209.197 - - [03/Dec/2012:04:06:01 -0800] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1406 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.14 Safari/537.17" "rprpfind.appspot.com" ms=23 cpu_ms=0 
    2012-12-03 04:06:01.265 / 500 350ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.14 Safari/537.17
    117.220.209.197 - - [03/Dec/2012:04:06:01 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.14 Safari/537.17" "rprpfind.appspot.com" ms=350 cpu_ms=80 loading_request=1 instance=00c61b117ca3c72030422ae0cb1dbc6ca386f09a
    E 2012-12-03 04:06:01.262
    /base/data/home/apps/s~rprpfind/1.363605572194595527/framework/bottle.py:96: DeprecationWarning: Python 2.5 support may be dropped in future versions of Bottle.
    E 2012-12-03 04:06:01.262
      warnings.warn(msg, DeprecationWarning)
    E 2012-12-03 04:06:01.262
    <type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>: invalid syntax (dammit.py, line 281)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~rprpfind/1.363605572194595527/main.py", line 6, in <module>
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~rprpfind/1.363605572194595527/bs4/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
        from .builder import builder_registry
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~rprpfind/1.363605572194595527/bs4/builder/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
        from bs4.element import (
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~rprpfind/1.363605572194595527/bs4/element.py", line 5, in <module>
        from bs4.dammit import EntitySubstitution
    I 2012-12-03 04:06:01.265
    This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162616/beautifulsoup-error-in-google-appengine

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to deploy to a Python 2.5 app engine instance.

BeautifulSoup 4 needs Python 2.7. Convert your code to use BeautifulSoup version 3, or upgrade your app engine instance to Python 2.7.

Comment: I have downloaded BeautifulSoup 3.2.1, but how to import it in my application? For BeautifulSoup 4, I wrote `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`, but what I have to write to import version 3?

Comment: See http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html, but you'll possibly need to adjust your code too, see http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#id12