# Beautiful Soup gives NULL

Tags: python, google-app-engine, null, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page=BeautifulSoup(page2)
self.response.out.write(page.title.string)
self.response.out.write("""<br />""")

mdays={}
mo={}
cost={}
ac={}
nc={}
month=(page.findAll('td',style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px", align="RIGHT"))

mo[0]=(month[0].contents)
mdays[0]=month[1].contents
cost[0]=month[2].contents
nc[0] = month[4].contents
ac[0]=month[5].contents
self.response.out.write(mo[0].string)
```

The first out.write statement prints the title,but the rest prints Null
The Beautful Soup code works properly on IDLE,but not on the AppEngine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162616/beautifulsoup-error-in-google-appengine